# Is there a way to control the font size in the equation in JupyterNotebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, r-markdown, jupyter, equation

In Jupyter Notebook markdown cells, is there a way to make the font size larger in the equation?

```
c = $\frac{a}{b}$
```

I tried`c = \large{$\frac{a}{b}$}` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a way to change de default equation size in a notebook, so we don't have to type Large for every equation?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The dollar signs start and end LaTex boundaries, and so you need to use the tag inside.

```
c = $\Large\frac{a}{b}$
```

UPDATE:
I have a comment below that points to [an image listing the tags and illustrating the relative sizes](https://texblog.org/2012/08/29/changing-the-font-size-in-latex/). I'm putting that link here in the post so that it is better featured.

Comment: Hi I found the font is a bit too big if I use 'large', I tried '\Medium' but it doen't work, what options we have? Thanks.

Comment: There is an image listing the tags and illustrating the relative sizes [here](https://texblog.org/2012/08/29/changing-the-font-size-in-latex/). I don't know if Jupyter supports all of them by default.

Comment: @Wayne Yes, thank you.  All but \footnotesize seem to be supported in Jupyter notebooks.